# Update all packages from GitHub

Tags: r, github

I know you can install packages from CRAN with this syntax:

```
install.packages(c("Rcpp"), dependencies=TRUE)
```

You can update all of them from CRAN with:

```
update.packages()
```

On the other side, you can install packages (compiling them) from GitHub with:

```
install_github("hadley/tidyr")
```

How can you upgrade all GitHub packages?

I mean without reinstalling (and compiling) them one at a time. Something like `update.packages()` for github.

Comment: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html

Comment: I am not sure , but maybe `update_packages` from `devtools` can help.

Comment: You can't, in general, because a _GitHub code repository_ is not a _R package repository_.  Hence the need for [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) which @Khashaa kindly pointed to already.  What you point out here is my major beef with `install_github()`.

Comment: rdocumentation.org knows a lot of packages that are on github and bioconductor. Shouldn't there be a way just to query this (or a similar) site for a download link? Maybe I'm missing a point though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
library(devtools)

#' Update all github installed packages.
#'
#' This will trash any non-master branch installs, and spend time re-installing
#' packages which are already up-to-date.
update_github <- function() {
  pkgs = loadedNamespaces()
  print(pkgs)
  desc <- lapply(pkgs, packageDescription, lib.loc = NULL)
  for (d in desc) {
    message("working on ", d$Package)
    if (!is.null(d$GithubSHA1)) {
      message("Github found")
      install_github(repo = d$GithubRepo, username = d$GithubUsername)
    }
  }
}

# test it:
# install github version of tidyr
install_github("hadley/tidyr")
library(tidyr)
update_github()
```

Don't run this if you have any github installations from anything more complicated than the master branch of user/repo. Also be careful if you have a lot of github installations, since this will blindly reinstall them all, even if up-to-date. This could take a long time, and also might break working packages if github master branches are not in tip top condition.

Take a look at devtools `R/session_info.r` for details.

Comment: OK. Thank you, Jack.  But it says "error trying to copy tidyr.dll..." when updating it

Comment: I'll try with a pkgs[!pkgs=="tidyr"]

Comment: Hmmm, works for me. Was there any other error information? Did it have this problem in a fresh R session?

Comment: maybe the antivirus didn't allow to replace some files, or Windows, I'm using W10. No other info. Anyway I can't check if it works again till any package gets updated at github.

Comment: It doesn't detect packages such as https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table  and anyway it says  "Username parameter is deprecated. Please use yihui/knitr"

Answer (score 10):

This works for me. It goes through all of the packages in your library, not only loaded packages.

```
update_github_pkgs <- function() {

  # check/load necessary packages
  # devtools package
  if (!("package:devtools" %in% search())) {
    tryCatch(require(devtools), error = function(x) {warning(x); cat("Cannot load devtools package \n")})
    on.exit(detach("package:devtools", unload=TRUE))
  }

  pkgs <- installed.packages(fields = "RemoteType")
  github_pkgs <- pkgs[pkgs[, "RemoteType"] %in% "github", "Package"]

  print(github_pkgs)
  lapply(github_pkgs, function(pac) {
    message("Updating ", pac, " from GitHub...")

    repo = packageDescription(pac, fields = "GithubRepo")
    username = packageDescription(pac, fields = "GithubUsername")

    install_github(repo = paste0(username, "/", repo))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**2019 update:**

The function `update_packages()` from the package [`remotes`](https://remotes.r-lib.org/index.html) ([one of the "offspring" of devtools](https://devtools.r-lib.org/#conscious-uncoupling)) now does a great job at updating packages from CRAN, GitHub, etc.

You might want to set some environment variables to make it work smoothly for you. [The README of the package on GitHub](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes) gives their list. In my case, this is what I have:

```
R_REMOTES_UPGRADE=always
R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS=true
GITHUB_PAT=<my GitHub personal access token>
```

Once set, all you have to do is:

```
remotes::update_packages()
```

to update all your packages.