# Where is Tidyverse dev version source code located?

Tags: r, github, dplyr, version-control, tidyverse

The dev version of dplyr introduces a new `across()` function that applies functions to a selection of columns. I can install the dev version of dplyr in R like this:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```

Before I install the dev version I'd like to examine the source code from [dplyr's github repo](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases). The problem is that it's not located there. Where is the dev version of dplyr located? Of any Tidyverse package for that matter?

Maybe when I issue the `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")` command it just installs whatever commits have been merged at that snapshot in time, to the latest release of dplyr?

Comment: You have the right link, [it's on the GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/b5ce7bb1d9d35c189679f8507096096949f750ad/R/across.R)

Comment: @IceCreamToucan maybe I need to rephrase the question, where is the entire dev version of the package located? Not just individual functions. Thanks for that though, that's the right function. The releases section of github only shows non-dev versions.

Comment: As far as I know the dev version is just whatever's currently in [the public repository](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr)'s master branch and won't have an official release tag. There's instructions for how to install it on that page, (`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")`) and you can browse the code from the website or click the green "clone or download" button to keep a local copy.

Comment: I think they develop a function on a branch then pull said branch across is already "done" so no branch for it, you can see on github.com the current branches being worked on, here is the across branch https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/4586

Answer (score 1):

I think they develop a function on a branch then pull said branch across is already "done" so no branch for it, you can see on github.com the current branches being worked on, here is the across branch [github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/4586](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/4586)

Comment: so whenever I issue the `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")` command it just installs whatever commits have been merged at that snapshot in time, to the latest release of dplyr?

Comment: I thought about that, and that is actually an excellent question, when I maintain R packages devtools always goes for the master branch, so that was my instinct when answering your question, if you don't install again from git hub does the package get outdated? I guess I have to read more about packages

Comment: I guess my update fear is solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538052/update-all-packages-from-github

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the right across function?

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/across.R

Comment: that's the right function and thank you. But I'm more interested in examining the entire dev version of dplyr. Is this located on github on something resembling the "releases" page in a complete form?

Comment: I found it on github: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr  in the R folder. 
 I assume that is the most recent across() function.  It was updated 6 days ago. 
 Looks like most other dplyr functions are there too. @JasonHunter